# Is there a way to say "Expand Everything" in OData?

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services, odata

Say I have an object that has 13 entities on it.

Having to expand them all when I am doing a generic select of data is tedious.

Is there way to expand all the objects on that object (but not sub objects)?  (I am referring to doing this in C# code, not in the OData URL.)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built in to do this.
You could write a helper method which would use reflection, inspect the type in question and determine the list of navigation properties and then add the expands for them on your query.
On the other hand, the reason expand is opt-in is that it comes at a cost (the payloads get larger really quick).